# How to call "ioctl" in Rust? And interface the Linux "tun" driver

Tags: linux-kernel, rust, tun

How can I the function  "ioctl" in Rust? Should I find a wrapper for it somewhere? Is there a de-facto wrapper? Or maybe it's already included in the standard Rust library? I've not found it, though.

Or, more generally, I need an interface the Linux "tun" driver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [`ioctl`](https://docs.rs/nix/latest/nix/sys/ioctl/index.html) in [`nix`](https://crates.io/crates/nix), which contains convenience wrapper of *nix functionalities.

Comment: yes, and there're iotcl packages out there as well. but popular is that one  and how much is it close to de-facto?

Comment: @Diime , currently `nix` has 325,649 downloads. I would say it's close to de-factor standard Unix api package in Rust.

Comment: ok. but how about this https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5b3cd3900ceda838f5798c30ab96ceb41f962534/src/libstd/sys/unix/c.rs#L78 ?

Comment: @Diime , it is a `unsafe` C declaration internally used by the compiler. We have a `libc` version here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libc/fn.ioctl.html On the other hand, `ioctl` in `nix` is safe.